# Creating Nodes Programmatically but cannot edit fields using Drupal once created

Tags: 7, nodes

I have a collection of nodes that are created programmatically after having created the content type using Drupal. This is the creation code:

```
    $node = new stdClass();
    $node->title = $vals->title;
    $node->type = "event_type";
    node_object_prepare($node);         
    $node->status                       = 1; 
    $node->promote                      = 0; 
    $node->comment                      = 0; 
    // title
    $node->title = $vals->title;
    // body     
    $node->body[$node->language][0]['value']   = $vals->body;
    $node->body[$node->language][0]['summary'] = text_summary($vals->body);
    $node->body[$node->language][0]['format']  = 'filtered_html';
    // intro text
    $node->field_event_type_intro = $vals->field_event_type_intro;
    // teaser
    $node->teaser = $vals->teaser;
    // data
    $node->data = $vals->data;
    // nodewords
    $node->nodewords = $vals->nodewords;

    $node = node_submit($node); // Prepare node for saving

    node_save($node);
```

This seems to be working but when I then click on one of these nodes to edit it it only shows the title in the edit screen. The body and intro are missing.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: do you solve your problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your code you have:

```
$node->field_event_type_intro = $vals->field_event_type_intro;
```

But if you want to add values to your fields you can use this:

- if is a text

  `$node->field_event_type_intro[LANGUAGE_NONE][0]['value'] = field_event_type_intro;`
- if is a taxonomy

  `$node->field_event_type_intro[LANGUAGE_NONE][0]['tid'] = field_event_type_intro;`
- if is a field reference

  `$node->field_event_type_intro[LANGUAGE_NONE][0]['target_id'] = field_event_type_intro;`